# PDFBox TextBox shows does no print

Tags: printing, pdfbox

I am adding a text field to a pre-existing pdf (W9) the code below places the text perfectly and I can view the saved file in acrobat but when I print it, it does not print the text field. What am I missing?

```
doc = PDDocument.load(in);
docCatalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
prAcroForm=docCatalog.getAcroForm();
page = (PDPage) docCatalog.getPages().getKids().get(0);
acroForm().setXFA(null);
PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
PDResources res = acroForm().getDefaultResources();

String fontName = res.addFont(font);
String defaultAppearance = "/"+fontName+" 7 Tf 0 g";

COSDictionary acroFormDict = acroForm().getDictionary();
acroFormDict.setBoolean(COSName.getPDFName("NeedAppearances"), false);

COSDictionary cosDict1 = new COSDictionary();
COSArray rect = new COSArray();
rect.add(new COSFloat(410f)); // lower x boundary
rect.add(new COSFloat(234f)); // lower y boundary
rect.add(new COSFloat(510f)); // upper x boundary
rect.add(new COSFloat(284f)); // upper y boundary

cosDict1.setItem(COSName.RECT, rect);
cosDict1.setItem(COSName.FT, COSName.getPDFName("Tx")); // Field Type
cosDict1.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.ANNOT);
cosDict1.setItem(COSName.SUBTYPE, COSName.getPDFName("Widget"));
cosDict1.setItem(COSName.T, new COSString("DATEFIELD"));
cosDict1.setItem(COSName.DA, new COSString(defaultAppearance));
PDTextbox textbox = new
      PDTextbox(doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm(), cosDict1);
textbox.setValue("This is It");

 try {
      page.getAnnotations().add(textbox.getWidget());
      acroForm().getFields().add(textbox);
      } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
cosDict1.setInt(COSName.F, 4);
```

this sets the print flag of the annotation widget.

Or call

```
textbox.getWidget().setPrinted(true);
```

Here's a screenshot of the items of the annotation widget of an existing field of the W-9 form:
[image]

Read [about these flags in the PDF specification](http://www.verypdf.com/document/pdf-format-reference/txtidx0607.htm).

Comment: Thanks it works.  Can you tell me what is this PDF Debugger?

Comment: The standard PDFDebugger can be downloaded as part of the PDFBox app from the download site http://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi#recent , see http://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/commandline.html#pdfDebugger for how to call. The version you see is the unreleased 2.0 version, get it here: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ The improvements were funded by google as part of the Google Summer of Code 2015.